# IcCube - List of Reports

Tags: list, report, iccube

In my system I would like to set up a Table of Contents for my users, meaning a list of all the reports they have access to. In /icCube/doc/ic3report I can see the structure, but I can nowhere find the files on my system.

So is it possible, to retrieve a list of reports somehow?

Comment: Do you want to retrieve the list of reports in Javascript ?

Comment: In Javascript or PHP, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The icCube Web Reporting framework is based on a Javascript visualization library ([www](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/viz/viz/doc/vizOverview.php)) that contains several requests; one of this request allows for retrieving the list of reports accessible by the user of the request:

```
getReportNames
```

You can modify an example to use this request and use a debugger to inspect the resulting table. Or if you have an instance of ic3.Reporting (see [www](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/reporting/doc/ic3OpenReport.php)) you can use the function:

```
ic3.Reporting.getAllReportNames( callback )
```

which is a shortcut of the underlying request usage. You can see a live example using this [URL](http://demo6.iccube.com/icCube/doc/ic3report/version/6.0.4?name=%2Fshared%2FStackOverflow%2FGet%20All%20Report%20Names%20Request&ic3demo&menu=on).

Hope that helps.